# Bold colors for mobile applications

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, color

I am aware that normal convention would have designers use more neutral colors for a mobile application.

In terms of entertainment based mobile applications: 
*Is it acceptable to follow a more bold or exciting approach?*

So rather than using calm colors, and an easy on the eyes approach, can a bold approach be used to give an app more of a *wow factor*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specific enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calm/easy colors that normal convention dictates isn't just there because they are a bland and boring app, it it because those colors have been tried and tested to allow users to look at the screen and use the app long without eye irritation and usability issues. It is a trend now for entertainment focused apps to use more bold colors to attract users and give a sense of excitement when using the app but you don't want to take to far as to scare them away.

Netflix:

[image]

Hulu:

[image]

Youtube:

[image]

You'll notice on all the apps I listed above, the main content areas are all neutral dark on light/light on dark colors. That is because the users will be looking there the longest. For areas the user won't be focused on long such as the login screen you can use more bright and bold colors to make your app exciting.